# How to get MethodInfo of Contains method of IQueryable<T> by reflection?

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I tried this:

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(Queryable).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] { typeof(TSource) });
```

but it returns `null`

specified the `BindingFlags`

```
  MethodInfo method = typeof(Queryable).GetMethod(
  name: "Contains",
  bindingAttr: BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static ,
  binder: null,
  types: new Type[] { typeof(TSource) },
  modifiers: null);
```

but still returns null

Comment: Use `method = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().Single(x => x.Name == "Contains" && x.GetParameters().Length == 2)` to get the `MethodInfo`, then `method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TSource))` to get an *invokable* one

Comment: The fact that `Queryable.Contains` takes at least two parameters should explain to you why this doesn't work.

Comment: @IanKemp If you [looked up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.contains?view=net-8.0#system-linq-queryable-contains-1(system-linq-iqueryable((-0))-0)) `Queryable.Contains` you would see that it is an extension method, thus the first argument is `this IQueryable<TSource> source`. So @haim770 was right after all and gave me the answer I was looking for. Thanks!